# Highcharts - Negative values, set y-axis to greater than 0?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and I'm trying to create a column chart where there are negative values, like their example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-negative/

However, I'm trying to figure out how to set the baseline 60. So that the x and y intersect at  -40 and anything below 65 is a negative data point.  I've been searching, but so far have only found threads that explain how to set min and max...

Comment: Did you try setting `min:60` for yAxis ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `threshold` option.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        threshold: 100
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9dWgL/.)

Comment: That's really cool - [couldn't find it in the docs though](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series).